# Display last N tweets where a person is mentioned

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, twitter

I'm looking to achieve the following:

For a specific person, let's say BarackObama, I'd like to see the last 100 times he was **mentioned**. So not his own tweets but the tweets of other persons containing @BarackObama.

I've been experimenting with the Twitter API, with success but hadn't succeeded achieving the above problem.

Thanks a lot in advance!
L

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search has a section titled Search Operators, check out the bit about "mentioning"

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I found the script below, this should give me what I need!
Needed to install Python on my server, forthermore nothing else.
Only the following problem still occurs:

**C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>get_tweets.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\get_tweets.py", line 32, in 
    csv_writer.writerow(('User','Tweet'))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface**

What could this mean ? Thanks!

```
## Retrieve a user's tweets
## Sample usage -- python get_tweets.py user_name_list.txt output.csv

##import urllib2
import sys
import csv
import urllib
##import simplejson
import json as simplejson
import traceback

COUNT=100

URL_LOCATION="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?"
params = {'include_entities':'true',
         'include_rts':'true',
         'screen_name':'Ilse_.....=>fill in username here',
         'count':COUNT
         }

def check_unicode(text):
    if isinstance(text,unicode):
        text = text.encode("UTF-8","ignore")
        return text
    elif isinstance(text,str):
        text= unicode(text,"UTF-8").encode("UTF-8","ignore")
    return text    

csv_writer = csv.writer(open(sys.argv[2],"wb"))
csv_writer.writerow(["User","tweet"])
user_list = open(sys.argv[1],"rb")
cnt=0
for each_user in user_list:
    print(cnt) 
    params['screen_name']=each_user
    encoded_url = urllib.urlencode(params)
    API_CALL = URL_LOCATION + encoded_url
    print(API_CALL) 
    try:
        data = urllib.urlopen(API_CALL).read()
        json_data = simplejson.loads(data)
        for each_timeline in json_data:
            csv_writer.writerow([each_user,check_unicode(each_timeline['text'])])            
    except:
        # Some Crap Failed !!!
        print(traceback.format_exc()) 
    cnt+=1
```